Transparent Animation skipping frames
I'm new to Blender.
I have a short animation that I need to export without a background, however when I export it with QuickTime encoding, the video ends up skipping many frames and looks like 1fps when I put it in a video editor (I tried it in Davinci and Blender's to see if it was related to the editing software but I got the same result, also no it's not my pc lagging).
I made sure to use QuickTime Animation video codec and to set Film to transparent. When I export the video in mp4 however everything is fine
Any idea?
I know I could just put a green plane behind the character but it'd look less good.

I wouldn't export into a video file to begin with. Rarely the best thing to do ;)

"looks like 1fps" - Is it 1fps? How did you verify this?

Hey, no it's not actually 1fps, I can see while it renders that all the frames are being rendered but it's just once I open it and try to use the video file, it's all laggy... And I'm also using the exact same settings when I tried exporting it in mp4 to see if it was the problem and everything was fine. Are there settings that get changed automatically when you set it to quicktime ?
